# How to specify the width and height of an image in android for sw600dp-port-tvdpi drawable?

Tags: android, image, android-drawable

I am a newbie to Android Designing. I am developing an app which should be suitable for Android devices including the 7 inch and 9 inch tabs.

I am at present designing for a `res`folder of the type `layout-sw600dp-port-tvdpi`.

I am using a `drawable` folder of the type `drawable-sw600dp-port-tvdpi`.

I have used an image 19px by 19px for `drawable-mdpi`. Can anyone guide me how to calculate the pixels required for the `tvdpi` drawable?

I have gone through the developer's site and found out how the pixels varies with mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi.

And lastly, how should I specify the size of the required images in android?

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tvdpi :

Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi.

More Details  : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Can I use mdpi*1.33 for both layout_port-tvdpi and layout-sw600-port-tvdpi?

Comment: @Ann,Sorry for late response but im not sure about it may it works so try this way then check what happen and glad to help you.